# angularjs $resource delete results in error

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to `delete` a resource using angular, which results in a `SyntaxError` in Chrome console. However, a correct server request is created and the resource does get deleted on the server.

script:

```
var libmsModule = angular.module('libmsModule', ['ngResource']);

libmsModule.factory('Book', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/libms/books/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});

libmsModule.controller('BookCtrl', function($scope, Book) {

$scope.deleteBook = function(index) {
    var bk = $scope.books[index];
    $scope.book = new Book();
    $scope.book.id = bk.id;
    $scope.book.$delete(function() {
        //console.log("deleting... " + index);
        //$scope.books.splice(index, 1);
    });
}

$scope.books = Book.query(function(data) {      
});

});
```

html:

```
<div id="home-container" class="home" data-ng-app="libmsModule">

<div data-ng-controller="BookCtrl">
<a href="#" data-ng-click="addBook()">Add Book</a>
   <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="book in books" data-ng-click="deleteBook($index)">{{book.id}} {{book.author}} {{book.title}} {{book.cost}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This results in:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8780/libms/books/44
Request Method:DELETE
```

Server (Spring MVC):

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/books/{id}" }, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteBook(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,
        Model model) throws Exception {
    logger.entry();
    bookSvc.deleteBook(new Book(id));
    logger.exit();
    return new ResponseEntity("Book deleted", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And the book is deleted accordingly, however the following is shown in the console:
[image]

The response tab (chrome console) says: `Book deleted`.
Do I need to add something for `delete` to the `Book Factory`?

Comment: Go to the "Network" tab in Developer Tools, inspect the response that you got for this request and see if there's anything odd

Comment: Seems like the problem is is interpreting the server response. What is the server response?

Comment: @tamakisquare, I have updated the question with my server side code. The response is a String 'Book deleted'.

Comment: @tamakisquare, adding produces = "text/plain" to RequestMapping on the Spring side fixed it. If you answer this question, I'll accept it. Although Pedro replied the same a few seconds later. :-)